# Is there a way to select items from an array based on time passed?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am building a day calendar. It has 8 boxes each representing an hour. I would like the the boxes in the past greyed out using moment. What I am thinking so far is this here:

```
var greyedOut = ["nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen",
  "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen"
]
var selected = [];

greyedOut.forEach(function(check) {
  selected.push(check)
})

console.log(selected);

if (moment().isAfter(moment(check))) {
  $()
};

var check = moment.duration(8, 'hours').asMinutes();
console.log(check);

let divvy = [480 / 8, 60 / 8];
console.log(divvy);
```

Thank you for any input or advice

Comment: What is `moment(check)` supposed to be? The only `check` is a local variable in the `forEach` loop.

Comment: Probably that `if` statement should be inside the `forEach`.

Comment: You said you have 8 hours in the calendar, but `greyedOut` has 9 elements.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but maybe this is close to what you want.

```js
greyedOut.forEach(function(check) {
  if (moment().isAfter(moment(check))) {
    $("#" + check).css("background-color", "grey");
  } else {
    selected.push(check);
  }
});

console.log(selected);
```

The test of `moment(check)` needs to be inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your input, sorry for not being clear. Yes I have 9 elements and there is 8 hours in the day. It looks like I have to compare the current moment to a starting point, 9am.